# How to return error response from Webhook in Logic app and keep webhook active until it successfully processes response?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have logic app with webhook action where it waits until it receives callback notification from my other application.

This other application sends the payload in a notification callback provided by webhook.

I need to validate this payload before I resume the logic app's execution with next step.

If validation fails, then I don't want webhook to unsubscribe. I want webhook active until it successfully receives response.

Comment: It's a bit confusing, can you restate with steps 1..2..3...etc?

Comment: Can you please include code to show your calls, registrations etc (not necessarily all the computations).

Comment: Sorry for making it confusing. I am working on approval flow.

Comment: Working on approval flow.  Steps.. 1) Http trigger receives request 2) sql action crstores request in database. 3) Webhook action creates call back URL  with Approve/ Reject possible actions. This call back URL is registered in database. 4) on UI application, approver can see notification with Approve/Reject actions. If Reject is selected then approver must submit rejection reason, 5)when webhook gets  callback notification it  checks if reason exists for rejected request, if reason is not provided it should return error and webhook call back URL should still be active so application can retry

Comment: adding some paragraphs for better reading of the issue/question

Answer (score 0):

You can have a validator Logic App in the middle.

- You keep your current **Main Logic App** with the Webhook which creates the
  callback URL and waits for approval or rejection.
- Your **approval app**, which gets the request with the callback URL, now instead of calling the callback URL, calls an intermediate **validator Logic App**. The **approval app** will send the Approval response and the callback URL as part of the request to the **validator Logic App**.
- Then, the **Validator Logic App** will respond to the **approval app** with the status: valid/invalid. And only when it's valid, will then call the callback URL of the **Main Logic App**.

HTH